# I'm trying to create an eventListener. Why won't it work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, mouseevent

I'm just trying to get the nav buttons to stay colored 'onclick'. I don't understand why it won't work... Can anyone help?

```
const about = document.getElementById('about-btn');

  about.addEventListener ('click' () => {
    about.style.backgroundColor = "#AAE0CE";
});
```

Comment: Add the missing `,` after `'click'`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have white spaces, which should give you errors anyways:

```js
const about = document.getElementById('about-btn');

about.addEventListener('click', () => {
  about.style.backgroundColor = "#AAE0CE";
});
```

Comment: A whitespace between `addEventListener` and `('click'` won't cause an error, no. The missing comma does

Comment: but still there should not be a whitespace in between, anyways, introduce formatting and linting to you project to avoid that stuff